# Close() for Session.connection() in hibernate 3.0 does not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session

I'm using Hibernate3.0, jdk 1.5 and jboss-4.0.3 and I need to use Session.connection() for direct SQL call on somewhere in my app.

Code looks like

```
String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = session.connection().prepareStatment(strSQL);
pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next())
{
    //do work
}
rs.close();
pstmt.close();
session.flush();
session.connection().close();
```

But on jmx-console, InUseConnectionCount keeps increasing untill it reaches

max-pool-size.

Anyone knows why session.connection().close() does not work?

Comment: `Session` is a wrapper for `java.sql.Connection`. You should only call `Session#close` and let Hibernate to close the internal `Connection` for you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I also tried session.close() and did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate, you have create an entity manager before you will be able to execute queries.

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence_unit_name");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

"persistence_unit_name" is the name of the persistence unit defined within your persistence.xml file.

Executing the query happens in the following way:

em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_ID = ?").setParameter(0, Integer.parseInt(id)).getResultList()